Is there a way to continue on research when there is no hope?
I am a PhD student in the final year of my studies, I am positive that I will get my degree. However, I have published only two papers, one in an A conference and one in a B conference. I have three more papers but those in my opinion are small contributions.
I am in CS and people have a lot of papers and an average student has at least one or two A* conference papers. But as I mentioned I have none. The research jobs including industry and national lab require A* papers. I am scared to even apply to those, and they might see my profile and laugh at me.
I tried my level best throughout my PhD. My professor has just started researching my topic, so she just gave me the subject name at the end of my two years, I have read multiple books and papers on my own and come up with my problem and solution, with no guidance as she does not know the subject. However, I am unable to reach the standard that A* conferences require.
I want to stay in research, anywhere in industry or national labs. Please let me know if there is some way. Is there a possibility to take a job and work on getting better papers and then go for a research job?
By the way, my work is on AR, so computer vision, neural networks, and robotics intersection.

Have you talked about this with your supervisor? Depending on the field (and niche), having a very useful expertise and good topical fit to a postdoc can compensate a less impressive publication record. Your supervisor might know groups/labs/companies that would be your closest topical fit.

Sorry for your troubles but this might be better on a board about your subject than here on Academia, which is very general.

‘[R]esearch jobs including industry and national lab[s] require A* papers,’ my emphasis. Would you share evidence of that, or at least explain where you get that idea?

@coffee_into_plots I approached my supervisor, but she said that this is a new topic for her as well she is not sure as to what a good next step for me is. She said that she did not want to steer me in the wrong direction as she is not aware of my research.

@Aruralreader Meta ``Preferred Qualification" (Publication track record at conferences such as NeurIPS, ICML, ICLR, etc.)
Postdoc requirement asks for papers in (NeurIPS, ICML, ICLR, CVPR).

It’s good you know your target audience. I wouldn’t say, however, Meta is representative of the industrial sector.

@Anamica Adding to what A rural reader said, Meta can dictate that they only want people applying who are publishing in top conferences because they're, well, Meta. There are PLENTY of other places doing research that are less "picky", for lack of a better term, about the tier of conferences that their prospective employees/postdocs are publishing in. You may have to adjust your sights lower than working for a FANG company right out of the gate, but you can still definitely have a career doing research with your publication history.

This answer applies only if you know you truly enjoy teaching, including introductory classes.  (This includes having enough teaching experience to know.)
You might consider looking for a job at a teaching-oriented college or university.  Teaching will be the primary focus of your job, but you will also be doing research, particularly research that can involve undergraduate students.  (Do keep in mind that the pay is often (though not always) quite low, and finding time to do enough research to remain competitive for more research-oriented jobs in the future is likely impossible.)

Thanks for the comment. I am more interested in research than in teaching.

As someone who took this direction (in maths), I can say that it may be your best chance. I have managed to make several meaningful research contributions, but just not at the rate of colleagues working in a research institution. If you aren't firing on as many cylinders as colleagues with the A* rated conference papers, it is probably best to accept this date and do your best with it.

Sorry for the spell correct: "date" should have been "fate". For the record, my goal in getting a PhD was to do research, full stop. I had no interest in a primarily teaching oriented job, although I am lucky enough to care about people and discharge my duties as a teacher. The fact is, finding your way into a research career requires many factors to align...not the least of which being the finding of a fruitful direction that people want to see progressed. In the end it is not about you, but about what the community wants to see accomplished.

While a strong publication history is certainly extremely helpful in getting jobs after a Ph.D., it is not the end of the world (or your career) if you graduate without them (though certain career paths may be more difficult than others.)
Try looking for postdoc positions. Some supervisors may hold your lack of publications against you, but many will prioritize other skills you can bring to their lab. You will need to be a bit careful - make sure that the labs you're looking to apply to are actively publishing, so that you can beef up your publication history. With a successful postdoc and the associated publications, future employers/research positions aren't going to really care that you didn't have many publications as a grad student.

@Anamica Also going to add this as a comment because it is somewhat specific to your situation and not a general answer - anecdotally, this is the path my career took. I had few publications as a grad student, and just completed a postdoc that was more fruitful (and am now hired in a full-time permanent research position.)

Thanks for the comment. I will look for suitable postdocs.

Similar to my situation i had a high risk PhD project from which I published little but learned a lot. My postdoc resulted in several publications and after that I got my first position
